# Behavior of Rindler modes for massless scalar field in 3+1 dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, unruh-effect

Thank you in advance for any answer to my question.
I'm having trouble understanding the behaviour of the mode functions of a massless Klein-Gordon field in Rindler coordinates. We are in 3+1 dimensions. For reference, take the review of the Unruh effect by Crispino, Higuchi and Matsas (2009); I will use the same notation. The coordinates are $ \mathcal{R}= (\tau , \xi, \vec{x}_\perp )$; in this coordinates system, the Klein-Gordon equation in the right Rindler wedge (with $m=0$) assumes the form

$$ \frac{\partial^2 \phi }{\partial \tau^2}= \left[ \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \xi^2} + e^{2a\xi} \left( \frac{\partial^2  }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2  }{\partial y^2} \right) \right] \phi $$

Assuming a solution of the form

$$v(\mathcal{R}, \omega, \vec{k}_\perp )= \frac{e^{-i \omega \tau}}{\sqrt{4\pi \omega}} \frac{e^{i \vec{k}_\perp \cdot \vec{x}_\perp}}{2\pi} g(\xi, \omega, \vec{k}_\perp) \, , $$
the function $g$ should satisfy the differential equation

$$ \left[ - \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \xi^2} + e^{2a\xi} k_{\perp}^2 \right] g = \omega^2 g \, \, \, (*). $$

Now, if $k_{\perp} \ne 0$, then g is given by the well-known solution proportional to the modified Bessel function of imaginary order $K_{i\omega/a} (k_{\perp} e^{a \xi}/a)$. However, if $k_{\perp} = 0$, then the previous differential equation reduces to that of a harmonic oscillator, and we should obtain $v \propto e^{i \omega \xi} $. I am fine with this, because it is as we were recovering the 1+1 dimensions mode function. What puzzles me is the way to recover the $k_{\perp} = 0$ case from the Bessel functions. In fact, for little values of $k_{\perp}$, one get the asymptotic form

$$ K_{i\omega/a} (k_{\perp} e^{a \xi}/a) \sim \frac{i \pi}{2 \sinh (\pi \omega/a)} \left( \frac{e^{i \omega \xi} \, (k_{\perp}/2a)^{i\omega/a}}{\Gamma (1+i\omega/a)} - \frac{e^{-i \omega \xi} \, (k_{\perp}/2a)^{-i\omega/a}}{\Gamma (1-i\omega/a)}\right) \, .$$

Terms such as $e^{\pm i \omega \xi}$ does in fact appear, but it seems to me that the quantities $k_{\perp}^{\pm i\omega/a}$ are not defined at $k_{\perp}=0$ (please correct me if I am wrong).

To be precise, my question is the following, divided in two parts.

1. Are my considerations about the solution of * for $k_{\perp}=0$ correct?
2. (a)If the answer to the first question is "yes", the function $g$ is continuous in $k_{\perp}=0$ (how to show it?), or we need to define it in two cases, in relation to whether $k_\perp $ is equal or not equal to $0$? (b) If the answer to the first question is "no", and one have to consider only the Bessel function, how does the case $k_\perp =0 $ works?

I couldn't find anything online that resolved my doubts. Any help will be truly appreciated. Thank you.